# Cannot Insert into SQL Server AlwaysEncrypted Table with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, always-encrypted

Absolutely going out of my mind with this, so please, any suggestions would be welcome.

I am running SQL Server 2016 with two encrypted tables:

hr_client

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[employee_id] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[honorific] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[first_name] [nvarchar](60) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[last_name] [nvarchar](60) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[gender] [char](1) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[date_of_birth] [date] ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[national_insurance] [nvarchar](9) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[start_date] [date] ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[end_date] [date] ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[position] [int] ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[department] [int] ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[manager] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[grade] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[salary] [decimal](10, 2) ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[status] [int] NULL,
[modify_date] [datetime] NULL,
[user_modify] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[active] [bit] NULL,
[type] [nvarchar](20) NULL
```

hr_grade

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[grade_id] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[description] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[min_rate] [decimal](10, 2) ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[max_rate] [decimal](10, 2) ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[overtime_1] [decimal](5, 2) ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[overtime_2] [decimal](5, 2) ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
[modify_date] [datetime] NULL,
[user_modify] [varchar](20) NULL,
[comments] [varchar](max) NULL,
[status] [int] NULL,
[active] [bit] NULL,
[type] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[position] [int] NULL,
```

I have setup the Column Master and Column Encryption Keys (currently stored on SQL Server). I have also setup Stored Procedures to Insert and Select data from these two tables. The data is encrypted as expected, and data can be inserted and returned using the stored procedures (all working fine direct in SSMS).

To access the data, I have created an ASP MVC application running on our internal IIS web server. The Application is targeting 4.6.1, and I use LinqToSql dbml for my SQL connection & commands. Connection String is as follows:

```
Data Source=EXAMPLE_IP;Column Encryption Setting=enabled;Initial Catalog=hr;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=EXAMPLE_USER;
```

Data can be inserted into, and selected from, the hr_grade table without issue.

However I can only SELECT from the hr_client table, and the INSERT (both direct or via Stored Procedure) fail on the following error:

```
Operand type clash: 
nvarchar(4000) encrypted with (
    encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', 
    encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', 
    column_encryption_key_name = 'EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME', 
    column_encryption_key_database_name = 'hr'
) is incompatible with nvarchar(20) encrypted with (
    encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', 
    encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', 
    column_encryption_key_name = 'EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME', 
    column_encryption_key_database_name = 'hr')
```

Now the only obvious difference I can see is that the hr_client table has NVARCHAR columns, which my application doesn't seem to like.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: The only obvious difference *I* can see is the NVARCHAR(4000) vs NVARCHAR(20). Not gonna try to reproduce your setup, please understand.

Comment: Well yes, that's obvious, but I'm not declaring NVARCHAR(4000) anywhere. Every call to the database fields use the respective field type and parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use profiler to verify, but I suspect Linq2SQL is declaring a parameter of type nvarchar(4000) to insert into a nvarchar(20) column.  With client encryption the SqlParameter type and length must match the target column, as the SQL Server can't perform any server-side conversion on the value.

You'll probably have to use EF or ADO.NET directly.

Comment: I feared as much, I would prefer to figure the issue out in Linq though as it's so much easier to use. Thanks for your suggestion, I will take a look at profiler

Comment: EF 6 is really no harder than L2S.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean in general, I just meant for me as I'm used to Linq

Comment: You were entirely correct, Linq automatically assigns string values to their (soft)maximum size of nvarchar(4000). Usually this isn't an issue, but as AlwaysEncrypted performs the encryption client side, then an implicit conversion cannot take place. It feels like a work around, but I've modified my fields to nvarchar(4000) and it works fine now

Comment: I just tested, and the client doesn't pad the cyphertext to the full length, so there's no real cost difference between declaring the column as nvarchar(20) and nvarchar(4000).

Comment: I had a very similar problem with Sql2Linq. @DavidBrowne-Microsoft not sure if I misunderstood but changing the data type (in my case from nvarchar(50)) to nvarchar(4000) did not solve the problem. In the end I changed the encryption type from Randomized to Deterministic which finally solved it for me. The data is not that critical in my case, but still not the best solution I feel.

Comment: Just been through this loop too and also ended up setting the encrypted nvarchar columns to nvarchar(4000), it was the only solution I could find.  Definitely feels wrong to be changing the database in order to meet the needs of the code, but that's a lot better than gutting Linq to SQL out of 300 classes..